# Serialization of python object using BinaryFormatter.Serialize

Tags: ironpython, python-2.6

I am using API for developing the extension and the API uses

System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter

to Serialize the pathon data types it works good until I am using builtin data types of python for storing data in variables for future use

but my problem is when I inherit one of the data types and try to restart the application it has problems while serializing and does not store the object

and I would like to know that is there any method I can make my objects Serializable without converting them to standard data types

for reference maybe following code helps

**Code**

```
from System import MarshalByRefObject  as MBRO
from System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary import BinaryFormatter  as BF
from System.IO import File
class SampleObject(MBRO):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3
        self.c =4
        self.d = 5

s=SampleObject()
st=File.Create(r"D:\users\*******\****\***********\test4")

bfo=BF()
bfo.Serialize(st,s)
st.Close()
```

**Error**

> SystemError: Type 'IronPython.NewTypes.System.MarshalByRefObject_4$4' in Assembly 'Snippets.scripting, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.